# Server says no routes are defined even though they are

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, localhost

I have defined three routes in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'pages#lottery'

  get 'pages/about'
  get 'pages/contact'
  get 'pages/lottery'

end
```

And when I run "rake routes" in my command line, I get the following:

```
      Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
         root GET  /                        pages#lottery
  pages_about GET  /pages/about(.:format)   pages#about
pages_contact GET  /pages/contact(.:format) pages#contact
pages_lottery GET  /pages/lottery(.:format) pages#lottery
```

But when I got to the localhost:3000/pages/contact I get the error:

```
"No route matches [GET] "/pages/contact.html.erb"
```

And also `"You don't have any routes defined!"`

Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: can you show your `pages` controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh rookie mistake. I had two tabs open in my command line. My `rails s` pages was in a different directory. Thanks for the help everyone, I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be going to the URL `/pages/contact.html.erb`, it should be just `/pages/contact.html`.

Rails provides nice helpers to make it easy to get the right path, for example, `pages_contact_path` (from your `rake routes`).

Answer (score -1):

Your `pages_controller.rb` should consist of three methods based on your routes listed.

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def lottery
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

**views/pages/contact.html.erb**

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Start up your rails server - `rails s` and navigate to `localhost:3000/pages/contact` and you should see `Hello World`

Comment: Actually, according to the Guide ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action), it is not necessary that the controller has the methods defined by the routes.

Comment: @jvillian what would you provide as a suitable answer?

Comment: Yeah I put those in there as an example as they were not in your original question, thought it could help. Looks like you fixed your error :)